# ssa() time series gapfilling R

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition

I have a question regarding gapfilling of time series, using the the R package {Rssa}.
The example series is of length 334 and contains several NAs.

```
b1 <- as.vector(B1.med[1,])
> str(b1)
 num [1:334] 0.0171 0.0331 0.014 0.0371 0.0149 0.0179 NA NA 0.0293 0.0096 ...
```

I want to use igapfill {Rssa} to fill my NAs. As igapfill wants an SSA shaped object, I have to do an ssa first, where a problem comes up:

```
> my.L = length(b1)%/%2
> s1.gap <- ssa(b1,L=my.L)
Error in ssa(b1, L = my.L) : 
  Nothing to decompose: the given field shape is empty
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  Some field elements were not covered by shaped window. 292 elements will be ommited
2: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  Nothing to decompose: the given field shape is empty
```

The help suggests (and has as default) a window length L of about half the data length, which just wouldn´t work for me. 
Only after going down with L to 23 I will not get this error message, but warnings still:

```
> s2.gap <- ssa(b1,L=23)
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  Some field elements were not covered by shaped window. 269 elements will be ommited

> summary(s2.gap) #for L=23

Call:
ssa(x = b1, L = 23)

Series length: 334, Window length: 23,  SVD method: eigen
Special triples:  0

Computed:
Eigenvalues: 1, Eigenvectors: 1,    Factor vectors: 0

Precached: 0 elementary series (0 MiB)

Overall memory consumption (estimate): 0.008934 MiB
```

But I won´t get more than 1 eigenvector until I further decrease (and still error messages).

```
> summary(s2.gap)  #for L=15

Call:
ssa(x = b1, L = 15)

Series length: 334, Window length: 15,  SVD method: eigen
Special triples:  0

Computed:
Eigenvalues: 15,    Eigenvectors: 15,   Factor vectors: 0

Precached: 0 elementary series (0 MiB)

Overall memory consumption (estimate): 0.01062 MiB
```

I don´t quite understand what my problem here is and google etc. have not helped me much either. I´m thankful for any advice :-)

Comment: `ssa` needs a series with no missing values (MVs). Do not trust in results given by `ssa` for series with MVs. You can start with the imputation of MVs using for example the package `imputeTS`.

Comment: It does work without NAs. It didn´t make sense to me that I need an ssa-object for filling NAs with `igapfill` but that `ssa`  doesn´t work with NAs. I will have a look into `imputeTS`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Probably, my answer is too late. Hope that it could be still helpful.)

Definitely, Rssa works with NA. However, the call of `ssa` before `igapfill` is really an unclear point in Rssa. The citation from the recent book [Singular Spectrum Analysis with R](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783662573785):
"Note that it is typical for the iterative approach to use the parameter value
`force.decompose = FALSE` in the preliminary call of `ssa` to avoid the decomposition,
which may be impossible due to the gap location."

That is, use `s1.gap <- ssa(b1, L=my.L, force.decompose = FALSE)` before the call of `igapfill`. Probably, the [companion web-site](https://ssa-with-r-book.github.io) to the cited book will be helpful for other tips.